# LaTeX gives Missing { inserted error

Tags: errors

I have written this:

```
\textcolor{blue}{? scalar alpha = 1\\
Generated scalar alpha = 1\\
? scalar omega = 1\\
Generated scalar omega = 1\\
? scalar beta1= 0.0\\
Generated scalar beta1 = 0\\
? scalar beta2 = 0.0\\
Generated scalar beta2 = 0\\
? scalar beta3 = 0.0\\
Generated scalar beta3 = 0\\
? scalar beta4 = 1\\
Generated scalar beta4 = 1\bigskip \\
? mle ll = -0.5*log(2*pi)-0.5(log(omega)+(e$^$2)/omega)}
```

And LaTeX gives me this error:

```
! Missing { inserted.
```

Double check many times, but don't know how to overcame this.

NB - Up to `\bigskip \\` works without problems.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The `$^$` bit is the problem. If your aim is to reproduce some program listing or output, you should consider the `listings` package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solved my problem using the command `\string^` in this way I can leave ^ showed in LaTeX output.

Comment: Well, this might be the solution to your question but it was not obvious at all what you tried to achieve because the posted code in you question was unclear and totally fragmented

Answer (score 1):

Insert `$^2$` instead of `$^$2`. Maybe you should also consider something like a `verbatim` environment for this kind of coding.

Comment: I've left this code `$^$2` on purpose in order to maintain the Gretl format.

Is there any possibility to force LaTex to display it?

For example when I'm typing `$\_$` I leave the underscore space.